# Split string with javascript regex with multiple tokens and considering escaped delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string in javascript using regex.

**Input:** `key1(name1,val1)key2(val2)`

**Expected Output:**

- key1
- name1,val1
- key2
- val2

If I use this `'key1(name1,val1)key2(val2)'.match(/[^\(\)]+/g)` it works fine for the above string but fails for the escaped parenthesis.

**Eg:** it fails for the following input `'key1(name\(1,val1)key2(val\)2)'.match(/[^\(\)]+/g)`.

**I want to allow \) and \( in the input value and it should not be considered while splitting.**

I want expected output as like:

- key1
- name\(1,val1
- key2
- val\)2

how can I achieve it using regex?

Comment: I think you have to escape the backslash `\\\`

Comment: Also worth noting that this would be *tons* easier if Javascript supported [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind), but [alas](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Comment: @jxpx777: No need for lookbehind in this case, still easy enough (but in general, I'm with you. JavaScript's regex engine isn't that great...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
result = subject.match(/(?:\\.|[^()])+/g);
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/bH5nT4).

**Explanation:**

```
(?:     # Start a non-capturing group that matches...
 \\.    # either an escaped character
|       # or
 [^()]  # any character except parentheses
)+      # one or more times.
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks Tim :)

Comment: This allows you to have (

Comment: @jxpx777: I don't think so - can you give an example?

Comment: Eep… I was thinking out loud and then realized I was wrong. Didn't intend to actually post that comment…

Comment: Looks like my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var re = /([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)/g,
    matches = [],
    input = "key1(name1,val1)key2(val2)";
while (match = re.exec(input)) { matches.push(match[1]); matches.push(match[2]) };

console.log(matches);
//=> ["key1", "name1,val1", "key2", "val2"]
```

Comment: thanks for a quick reply your regex almost works for me, but there is a small correction done in my expected output I expect second value as 'name\\(1,val1' and not 'name(1,val1'

Comment: But your original input doesn't have `\(`? Why do you want this in output then?

Comment: In my second example I have said that its failing for this input **key1(name\\(1,val1)key2(val2)**

Comment: That should be written as: `key1(name\\(1,val1)key2(val2)`

Comment: your solution does not work if the input string contains escaped closing parenthesis. **key1(name\\\)1,val1)key2(val2)**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do this as well

Include newlines:

```
 # (?:[^()\\]+|\\[\S\s])+

 (?: [^()\\]+ | \\ [\S\s] )+
```

Exclude newlines:

```
 # (?:[^\n()\\]+|\\.)+

 (?: [^\n()\\]+ | \\ . )+
```

Perl test case

```
$/ = undef;

$str = <DATA>;

while ( $str =~ /(?:[^\n()\\]+|\\.)+/g )
{
    print "'$&'\n";
}

__DATA__
key1(name1,val1)key2(val2)
key3(name\(3,val3)key4(val4)
```

Output >>

```
'key1'
'name1,val1'
'key2'
'val2'
'key3'
'name\(3,val3'
'key4'
'val4'
```

Comment: your solution also does not consider \\) in input string. I want to allow **\\)** and **\\(** in the input value and it should not be considered while splitting.

Comment: @Anks - Really? Tim Pietzcker's solution of 2 hours ago, that you accepted is _my_ solution dummed down. The difference is mine runs about 5 times faster and I answered 22 hours ago. Your comment is lamely false, it considers all escaped characters as seen from my test case. I suggest you try things out before such statemens!